# Laravel repeated select list validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I have form that has a repeated select list like the following:

```
<select class="form-control set-25" name="equipments[:selectName:-1]">...
<select class="form-control set-24" name="equipments[:selectName:-2]">....
<select class="form-control set-8" name="equipments[:selectName:-3]">....
```

I want to validate each one of those lists.

```
public function installCavitySave(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate(request(), ['equipments.*' => 'required']);
       dd(request());
    }
```

However, the rule does not work. When I tried `$this->validate(request(), ['equipments' => 'required'])` It works only if there is no any select option values selected but if one of them is selected the validation allow others to be null.

I need the validation to validate every select list named `equipments[x]` where `x` is any key supplied to the elements name attribute.

Comment: is it always tree select boxes?

Comment: @Sletheren no it may be one, two, three, four, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your Laravel validation rules. It's your inputs. If your select has no options, then the index does not exist in your request, which is why the validation rule will still pass because it will not loop through the index.

You can check if you are receiving the select indexes properly:

```
dd($request->input('equipments.*'));
```

If you add an empty option field by default:

```
<form method="POST">
    <select class="form-control set-25" name="equipments[:selectName:-1]">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="test">Test</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control set-25" name="equipments[:selectName:-2]">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="test">Test</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control set-25" name="equipments[:selectName:-3]">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="test">Test</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then in your controller:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'equipments.*' => 'required'
]);
```

The errors you will receive:

```
array (size=3)
  'equipments.:selectName:-1' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'validation.required' (length=19)
  'equipments.:selectName:-2' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'validation.required' (length=19)
  'equipments.:selectName:-3' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'validation.required' (length=19)
```

Comment: I have generated those lists using Laravel Collective Form. and I used the placeholder property. it already prints out an empty select option like `<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" value="">Select</option>`

Comment: @SaidbakR Run the following `dd($request->input('equipments.*'));` to check if you receive the indexes in your request properly. Take note that disabled inputs are not sent with the request.

Comment: @SaidbakR I just tested it with disabled attribute, the request does not receive your selects. This is why the validation is passing. You have to remove the disabled attribute.

Comment: @SaidbakR If you don't want the user to select the placeholder option, you can remove the disabled and add a `display: none;` on them. So once the user chose an option, he cannot chose the placeholder again. And if they chose nothing, it will fail the validation.

Comment: I'm trying to remove the disabled attribute from the placeholder but I could not able to figure it out.

Comment: @SaidbakR Instead of doing `Form::select('equipments[:selectName:-1]', ['test' => 'Test'], null, ['placeholder' => '']);`, you can add an empty option to your list of options: `Form::select('equipments[:selectName:-1]', [null => '', 'test' => 'Test']);`

Comment: I have managed to remove the placeholder and making the initial option state to be white space. the validation run for each select list but without validation message

Comment: @SaidbakR Can you update your question to show me what your selects look like? Also, can you add the `dd($request->input('equipments.*'));`?

Comment: Well, I solved the elements message issue by including a form message layout:
`@include('layouts.form-error')` It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a function like this:

```
public function validate_array($request){
  $rules = [];
  foreach($request->get('equipments') as $key => $val)
  {
    array_push($rules, ['equipments.'.$key => 'required']);
  }
  return $rules;
}
```

and then validate the rules, using `$this->validate;` like so:

```
public function installCavitySave(Request $request)
{
  //validate select boxes
  $rules = $this->validate_array($request);
  $this->validate($request,$rules);
}
```

Comment: Where is could I place this function and how to use it?

Comment: `Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\JobController::$request` and it meant by `foreach($this->request...`

Comment: I modified it, you will pass the request to the function